# how to normalize angle radian value to 2*pi?

Tags: elixir

I have to adjust the angle's radian value between [0,2*pi) if it is negative angle or too big angle than 2*pi.

My code is as follows, and I haven't found the related library:

```
def normalize(angle) do
  rem(round(angle * 1000), round((2 * :math.pi * 1000))) / 1000
end
```

Is there a better way to improve it?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Do you mean you want to convert degrees to radians (your function does not do that correctly though)?

Comment: The purpose has been added as above.

Comment: So you have radians as an arbitrary value and you want to receive back radians normalized (in the interval `[0,2π)`,) correct?

Comment: Yes. `rem`'s requirement is integer, so code become above. but I think it can be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I properly understood the intent, what you need is to add/subtract the integer number of `2π`s to bring the angle to the interval. Use [`Kernel.floor/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#floor/1) to calculate the number of full turnarounds. Luckily enough, it works for negative numbers out of the box, thanks to wise `floor/1` implementation.

```elixir
angle - 2 * :math.pi * floor(angle / (2 * :math.pi))
```